# isnull and column creation

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following SQL appends a "Reported" column in to an existing table:

```
isnull(ftemp.[reported],1) as [Reported]
```

I have not created columns this way before and am a little confused about how to ensure it is an integer column. Where do I add the INT?  It defaults to string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should not default to a string.  But if you want an integer, then cast the value:

```
cast(isnull(ftemp.[reported], 1) as int) as Reported
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a computed column, and will take whatever the type of the expression is.

In this case I will quote from [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#return-types) for `ISNULL`:

> **Return Types**
>
> Returns the same type as check_expression. If a literal NULL is
> provided as check_expression, returns the datatype of the
> replacement_value. If a literal NULL is provided as check_expression
> and no replacement_value is provided, returns an int.

So the result of `ISNULL` will always be the type of the first value.